# Is it possible to download Objective-C and execute it within Webkit?

Tags: ios

I'm investigating the feasibility of developing a native (hybrid) app based on HTML/Javascript (using UIWebView) that once installed is capable of downloading and executing more html and javascript and objective-c*.
The Objective-C code would be invoked by the HTML/Javascript code.

I'm thinking the Objective-C would have to be complied into a static library. Would this work, or are there any other means/mechanisms available?

- The guidelines say this:
  "3.3.2 An Internal Use Application may not download or install  executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if  all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and  not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code  downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework."

Note how it says *scripts and code* can be downloaded and run by Webkit.

Comment: I believe there are security measures in place that prevent such code from being executed via `UIWebKit`. Otherwise, there would be an epidemic of malware.

Comment: Isn't Webkit sandboxed? That's why the guidelines make an explicit exemption for scripts and code downloaded and executed within Webkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML/JS/CSS should be fine, but downloading and executing Objective-C code is not allowed by Apple and will result in rejection/quick removal of your app from the App Store

Comment: "3.3.2 An Internal Use Application may not download or install  executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if  all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and  not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code  downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework." So it says downloading and executing scripts and code is permitted. Javascript would be an example of downloading and executing scripts. So what is the code it is referring to that is permissable to be downloaded/executed?

Comment: Code is everything that is not run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework. So JavaScript/HTML/CSS is fine. WebKit is the browser engine used by Safari/Mobile Safari and Chrome.

Comment: If Objective-C code is invoked from Javascript code that is executed within WebKit, then does the sandboxing that applies to the Javascript execution also apply to the Objective-C execution? If so then in principle it ought to be allowed as the reasons for the rejection would be on grounds of security, yet if the Objective-C code is still sandboxed also its just as secure as the JavaScript isn't it?

Comment: You can't invoke Objective-C directly with JavaScript, you can do it the way PhoneGap does it by registering a custom URL scheme for your App and the call something like this `myapp://parameter1/parameter2/` within the UIWebView and than do what you need to do in your App Delegate's `application:handleOpenURL:` method. Again, you are not allowed to download Objective-C code and execute it -> Example of someone who did: http://modmyi.com/content/5841-recently-discovered-ios-security-exploit-allows-users-information-accessed.html

Comment: How about this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD

Comment: Does that app use Webkit? My argument (apologies for sounding pedantic) is that *if* the iOS security/sandboxing mechanism is implemented in terms of something like a process model (like on Symbian OS) then Objective-C executed using a PhoneGap like mechanism would still be executing within the Webkit sandbox and hence should be secure, and hence in principle should be no different from executing Javascript within Webkit. Maybe the Webkit sandboxing doesn't extend to Objective-C then? Or its an example of inconsistency.

Comment: Charlie Miller did not use WebKit, he downloaded code (Objective-C) after the App has been approved by Apple and executed it. That's why they kicked him out of the Developer Program

Comment: Which is not therefore an argument against my point - which is that if all of this is done within Webkit and if the webkit sandbox extends to Objective-C invoked from Webkit (as it does to Javascript invoked from Webkit) then there are no security issues. Once again I reiterate the point in apple's own documentation - "The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.". They don't say what code or what scripts, if everything loaded from within Webkit is secure due to the Webkit sandbox then *in principle* all scripts/code is valid.

Comment: Webkit is a browser engine and can NOT run Objective-C but JavaScript. Should be a better argument ;-)

Comment: But it can invoke, if not execute, Objective-C, the question is therefore does its sandboxing model extend to that invoked code.  If Apple were to permit something like this, would a static library work?

Comment: Maybe there is precedent for relaxation of rules on a case by case bases http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/04/ios-and-javascript-for-real-this-time       ;-)

Comment: You can't invoke Objective-C from JavaScript, you can just use the PhoneGap way but in that case, the JS just gives your App parameters. Everything from that point on needs to be implemented by you and is therefore plain Objective-C code that has to be in your app when you submit it to Apple for review.